# Printing Jasper Reports in Local and Network Printer

Tags: java, printing

I have a web application running using Struts2 framework. The requirement is

a. User's perform various transactions. 
b. Each transaction needs to be printed. 
c. Each transaction has a jrxml attached to it (configured using a property file). 
d. Once the user completes the transaction, print should happen seamlessly.

Printing can be done in two ways. 
1. If a Network printer is configured for that particular user and the transaction, the print will be fired in that particular network printer. 
2. If a Local Printer (attached to the desktop) is configured for the user, the print should be fired in his local printer.

I have achieved the first part (network) printing using Java Print Services. But need a solution around the local printing requirements. 
For local printing, once the user completes the txn, the report should be printed to his local printer, without any user intervention. 
User may have more than one printer installed to his local machine, based on the txn type routing will happen to the appropriate local printer. I have looked for options using JavaScript but not getting a clear solution, don't want any popup or iframe to be used.

Any help or suggestions would be of great help.